# Error on authentication React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to implement search feature to search images from unsplash.com using unsplash api. But for some reason I can't get the authentification right. I am getting a NetworkError.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Unsplash, { toJson } from 'unsplash-js';
import './App.css';

const unsplash = new Unsplash({
  applicationId: '',
  secret: '',
  callbackUrl: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  headers: {
    "Accept-Version": "v1"
  }
});

    class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const authenticationUrl = unsplash.auth.getAuthenticationUrl([
      "public",
      "read_user",
      "write_user",
      "read_photos",
      "write_photos"
    ]);
    location.assign(authenticationUrl);
    unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code)
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        //console.log(unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code))
        unsplash.auth.setBearerToken(json.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Auth err', err));

  }

  // handleClick() {
  //   let query = document.getElementById('input').value;
  //   fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?query=' + query)
  //     .then(response => console.log(response))
  //     //.catch(error => console.log('error: ' + error));
  // }

  handleClick() {
    let query = document.getElementById('input').value;
    unsplash.search.photos(query, 1) //function provided by api
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form id='form'>
          <input type='text' id='input' ></input>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' onClick={this.handleClick} ></input>
        </form>
        <div id='field' >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Api documentation is https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#authorization if that helps. I never had experience with authentication.

Comment: can you show an error (screen or code)?

Comment: ./src/App.js
  Line 25:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: I don't know why you would need to use `location` in your case. Can you comment/remove that line and show the error you get afterwards? (preferably by editing your question so others can see it easily)

Comment: it seems like a lint error, but not a NetworkError

Comment: no error if I comment location out, but then when I try searching it gives me Network Error. Something about Blocked "Cross-Origin" request

Comment: is it happens on componentDidMount or on handleClick?

Comment: also what this means `'mountain'.code`? There is no `code` property on string

Comment: On onClick. It only happens when I press submit

Comment: In api documentation that I linked there is a line `unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code)`, and it gave me error that query is not defined so I figured that I can just hardcode that query

Comment: pro tip: use Vue instead of React

Comment: _I figured that I can just hardcode that query_ 
But that's wrong. In example query - is an object, so to hardcode it just use simple string `'mountain'` instead of `'mountain'.code`

Comment: Yeah, that still doen't work. I don't even know where to begin fixing this

Comment: so, it seems you are not authorised. Can you log token there `unsplash.auth.userAuthentication('mountain'.code)` - in last `then`?

Comment: `Promise { "pending" }
​
<state>: "pending"
​
<prototype>: PromiseProto { … }`

Comment: I mean can you try this
```unsplash.auth.userAuthentication('mountain')
      .then(string => JSON.stringify(string))
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json.access_token);
        unsplash.auth.setVearerToken(json.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Auth err'), err);```

Comment: I edited the code and now I cant seem to get around a few errors `./src/App.js
  Line 29:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 30:  'query' is not defined        no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error. index.js:2178
./src/index.js
8:36-39 "export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App'`

Comment: can you update your code?

Comment: I updated the code now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176047/discussion-between-ilia-and-snakescantwearboots).

Answer (score 0):

Where Unsplash's documentation suggests passing the argument `query.code` to `unsplash.auth.userAuthentication`, I believe they're intending for you to parse your query string and declare the value of `query` first.

You could use a library such as [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) to help you to achieve this.

Comment: oh, but where do I use that query-string? when I run the app I get redirected to the authentication code and then I just see errors